# AngularJS caching batch entity GET to individual entity services?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-http, angularjs-rootscope, cachefactory

So I have an endpoint which returns the contents of many entities in parallel.

I have a shared service which calls this endpoint and puts them into a shared `$cacheFactory`.

When `GET /base_entity/<id>/all` route is hit *first*, then `GET /entity/<id>` should return the cached copy.

What's best-practice in telling the `GET /entity/<id>` service to not perform an HTTP get until `GET /base_entity/<id>/all` has had a chance to complete?

`$broadcast`/`$emit` approach seems odd. I suppose I could use that shared `$cacheFactory` with `cache.put('START /all for ID:' +, id)` and `cache.put('FIN /all for ID:' +, id)`, but not sure if that's a strange way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a new view and controller. The controller's `constructor` calls `GET /base_entity/<id>/all` and caches it then does a `$state.go` passing along current `$stateParams`. Concurrently the view shows a shiny graphic loading `directive`.

Now when `/entity/<id>` state is transitioned to, the service first checks ALL cache; updates its cache accordingly; then checks cache and returns that in a `$q` promise, or hits `$http` otherwise.